# Rotate arc in SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to draw a Doughnut Chart by SVG tag. I draw every 1 piece of the graph. I use Path with property : stroke-dasharray. But it is not absolutely correct. I want use property transform="translate and rotate" to rotate pieces of the graph. Please, help me! Thank you.

[image: Chart outline appears and i dont want this]

```
    <path 
    d="M 100 100 0 a 10 10 0 0 1 0 20 a 10 10 0 0 1 0 -20" 
    stroke-linecap="butt" 
    stroke="arrayColor[i]" 
    stroke-width="10"
    stroke-dasharray= "C * i / 5,  C" 
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of drawing an entire circle and clip it with `stroke-dasharray` to a circle-segment, how about drawing the circle segment in the first place?

A utility function that produces the path for a circle-segment and a little bit of code showing how you could use it to build the entire doughnut.

```js
function roundNumbersToSomethingReasonable(strings) {
  return strings.reduce((acc, str, i) => acc + Math.round(arguments[i] * 1000) / 1000 + str.replace(/\s+/g, " "));
}

function circleSegment(x, y, radius, inner = 0, startAngle = 0, endAngle = 360) {
  startAngle *= Math.PI / 180;
  endAngle *= Math.PI / 180;
  inner = Math.max(inner, 0);

  const s0 = Math.sin(startAngle),
    c0 = Math.cos(startAngle),
    s1 = Math.sin(endAngle),
    c1 = Math.cos(endAngle),
    largeArc = +(Math.abs(endAngle - startAngle) > Math.PI),
    sweep = +(endAngle > startAngle);

  return inner ?
    roundNumbersToSomethingReasonable`M${x + c0 * radius} ${y + s0 * radius}
      A${radius} ${radius} 0 ${largeArc} ${sweep} ${x + c1 * radius} ${y + s1 * radius}
      L${x + c1 * inner} ${y + s1 * inner}
      A${inner} ${inner} 0 ${largeArc} ${1^sweep} ${x + c0 * inner} ${y + s0 * inner}
      z` :

    roundNumbersToSomethingReasonable`M${x + c0 * radius} ${y + s0 * radius}
      A${radius} ${radius} 0 ${largeArc} ${sweep} ${x + c1 * radius} ${y + s1 * radius}
      L${x} ${y}
      z`;
}

const data = [{
    value: 30,
    color: "red"
  },
  {
    value: 10,
    color: "green"
  },
  {
    value: 17,
    color: "blue"
  }
];

const total = data.reduce((total, item) => total + item.value, 0);
let angle = -90;

this.foo.innerHTML = data.map(item => `<path fill="${item.color}" d="${circleSegment(0, 0, 50, 30, angle, angle += item.value / total * 360)}" />`)
  .join("\n");
```

```html
<svg id="foo" viewBox="-50 -50 100 100"></svg>
```

I'm aware that this ain't the question you've asked but imo. a better solution to your problem.